# Multiple references to a footnote

Tags: xetex

I've looked at a number of issues with similar description but none of the solutions quite fits the bill.

Does latex allow this:

… which reminds me of the Caceres¹, Murillo², and Heredia³…

with Cáceres, Murillo, Heredia pointing to a footnote that would look something like this:

1, 2, 3. Well-known wineries in La Rioja, Spain.

Obviously, this only makes sense when the common footnote is referenced by words that belong to the same sentence and will end up on the same page, preferably with no intervening footnote reference(s).

Anyone seen anything like this?

TIA…

Comment: Why not use the same number for each reference to the footnote?

Comment: For one thing I have no idea how I would do that since the numbering of the footnotes is handled by latex automatically. But more to the point it would be confusing for the reader who would probably think that it is a typo.

Comment: It's perhaps unusual, but not unknown, to make multiple references to the same footnote.  A footnote can be given a label, which can then be referenced.  This might work: `Caceres,\footnote{xxx}\label{ftnt:wineries} Murillo,\textsuperscript{\ref{ftnt:wineries}} ...`.  (Not tested.)

Answer (score 1):

The `memoir` class provides for this; see Chapter 12 *Page Notes* in the manual (`>texdoc memoir`). The macro to use is `\footref` referencing a label given in the footnote.

```
...\footnote{kerning ...\label{fn:kern}
... 
... The footnote\footref{fn:kern} on \pref{fn:kern} ...
```

will produce something like: *The footnote(16) on page 110 ...*

Answer (score 0):

Thank you barbara beeton. I tested your suggestion and after the second xelatex pass I could see a superscript "1" next to "Caceres" as expected but nothing next to Murillo. Interestingly after the first pass I remember seeing two question mark superscripts next to Murillo… so my guess is that latex **does** try to print something but there is nothing there (in the footnote counter variable so to speak) to print. In any event even if latex printed all three 1-2-3 superscripts I don't see how I could figure out a way to make him start the footnote with "1, 2, 3." in the same fashion as the other footnotes in this document (and there are many of them) and I have a feeling what I am trying to do is really asking for trouble anyway… probably would end up messing up my footnote numbering or something. In any case since these three footnotes are going to end up on the same page in sequence, I'll just code something like this:

1. wineries … etc.
2. *Ibid.*
3. *Ibid.*

P.S. Since for some reason the system has flagged me as a disreputable character with "less than 50 points" (?)… I was unable to reply to your post and had to reply to my own post.

Thanks,

BS.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge). The message you got means that you have to earn some reputation (points)  to be able to do what you tried ...